# Can I fetch Calories and Steps real time to update my app from Watch app?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit

I searched everywhere but I don't find any proper answer related Watch App.

So, my question is Can I fetch Calories and Steps real time to update my app from Watch app?

Is there any way to keep my app up to date of Calories and Steps?. Also there any way I get directly steps and calories from watch app to my app without watch app?

I know I can get steps and calories from Health kit but its not real time they will update in sometime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CMPedometer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmpedometer/) to get more real-time steps data. Note that this is data that is generated on the watch and will not include any steps data synced from phone (HealthKit will consider both data streams in its results). Calorie data is only accessible through HealthKit.